# Pandas Using index of pandas dataframe to update another dataframe on same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes.  I am trying to update `df` with values from `df2` based on matching index's.

```
df
    Url_Sub_Fld     ip
0   tel             na
1   li              na
2   192.22.25.26    192.22.25.26

df2
   Url_Sub_Fld
1  test_string
```

Desired output:

```
df
    Url_Sub_Fld     ip
0   tel             na
1   test_string     na
2   192.22.25.26    192.22.25.26
```

Comment: `df.update(df2)` works fine or even `final=df2.combine_first(df)` , note update is an inplace operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been 22 hours and no Answers so I will post anky_91's comment as it is what I used to solve my problem.

```
df.update(df2['Url_Sub_Fld'])
```